# Deploy files in Magento2 while theme developement

Tags: magento2

When developing, do I need to clear caches everytime I change a file?

I have set my env to `developer` with

`$ php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Magento now build Symlinks to my themes file for each file that has to be loaded. However, if I make a change to a `*.css` file and save it, no changes are made.

Therefore I delete the whole cache everytime I change something, which is quiet a pain.

I do so with:

`$ rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* var/tmp/*`

Logically Magento has to rebuild all this stuff. This is time consuming. How can I speed up things? Can I delete specific files directly and if so, where do I find them?

My Cache Settings are:

```
Current status:
                        config: 0
                        layout: 0
                    block_html: 0
                   collections: 1
                    reflection: 1
                        db_ddl: 1
                           eav: 1
         customer_notification: 1
                     full_page: 0
            config_integration: 1
        config_integration_api: 1
                     translate: 1
             config_webservice: 1
```

Comment: While you are developing, is there a reason you need to keep cache on? It's typically the first thing i disable when i start a project and only enable it when i'm ready to test before deploy.

Comment: See my edit, good catch! Forgot to paste it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty easy. Just delete the CSS folders, nothing else.

`rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Vendor/Theme/de_DE/css/* pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/de_DE/css/* var/tmp/*`

Loads fast, works nice. JS doesnt need a clean cache, since it does symlinks, as said.

Comment: as a side note, if you have Grunt set up in your work flow, you can run the commands `grunt clean` grunt exec` then `grunt less` and it will effectively do the same thing. After running through this once, you can run `grunt less:{your_theme}` after that and it should recompile all your styles. It might not be the best solution for your case, but it might be worth a try.